# Modified Chlorophyll Absorption Ratio Index (MCARI) vs Green Chlorophyll Index (GCI) in a desert

Tags: r, remote-sensing, ndvi, vegetation-index

I am using UAV multispectral data to compute different vegetation indices. Both of these indices were computed with the purpose of seeing/assessing the `chlorophyll` content, thus indicating if the plant is stressed or not.

I am using the 'RSToolbox' package to calculate `MCARI`. MCARI indicates the relative abundance of chlorophyll. Daughtry et al. (2000) simplified the CARI index to minimize the combined effects of soil and non-photosynthetic surfaces. MCARI should be interpreted together with NDVI or LAI. One of the bands required for MCARI is `rededge1` which according to `?RSToolbox::spectralIndices` ranges from `680-720 nm`. The formula for MCARI is:

```
((redEdge1 - red) - (redEdge1 - green)) * (redEdge1/red)
```

Then I calculated `GCI`, which is used to estimate the content of leaf chlorophyll in various species of plants. The chlorophyll content reflects the physiological state of vegetation; it decreases in stressed plants and can therefore be used as a measurement of plant health. GCI formula:

```
GCI = (NIR / (Green) – 1
```

Which of these two indices are more suitable for such a landscape? The UAV data was collected in April 2021.
Code

```
library(RStoolbox)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(tidyverse)

# Load the multispec raster
Mutlispec = raster("path/Multispec.tif")

# Compute MCARI Modified Chlorophyll Absorption Ratio Index
MCARI = spectralIndices(Mutlispec, red = 1, green = 2, redEdge1 = 5, indices = "MCARI")

# Compute the Green Chlorophyll Index (GCI)
GCI = (Mutlispec$nir / Mutlispec$green) - 1
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do the papers describing these indices mention any limitations dependent on the landscape type? What do you get if you do a scatterplot of one vs the other from your data? If they are strongly correlated then they're essentially going to do the same job.